# Accessibility Service issue - Android

Tags: java, android, accessibilityservice

I am using accessibility service in my android application. When app is removed from recent and opened again the data in static variables is still there. When I remove accessibility service from the app it works fine and data in static variables is removed on reopening the app.

I want the app to behave normally as it usually does without accessibility service. How can I achieve this?

**Mainfest.xml**

```
<service
        android:name=".AccessibilityService.MyAccessibilityService"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.accessibilityservice" android:resource="@xml/accessibility_service_config" />
    </service>
```

**MyAccessibilityService.java**

```
    public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {

    @SuppressLint("RtlHardcoded")
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {
    }
}
```

**accessibility_service_config.xml**

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description"
android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeWindowContentChanged|typeWindowStateChanged"
android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
android:notificationTimeout="100"
android:accessibilityFlags="flagReportViewIds|flagRetrieveInteractiveWindows"
android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Accessibility Services are bound to the System service and have the lifecycle of the System service. Because these services are used by people with disability. These services run even when the app that defines them is closed. So, you could perhaps use a hack to do things like these for changing your static variables:

When you open the app, the `onCreate` of the `MainActivity` is called. So, in your `onCreate` you could set the values of those static variables to the default value you want. But remember that these don't work with instance variables defined in AccessibilityServices.

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       //Your other activity code.
       //Here you can reinitialize those different values
       MyService.aValue = true
    }
```